# Reading files from path directory not working

Tags: python, ioerror

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

When reading from the Desktop/file path.  Testing the read() function.

Tried a number of files to open in Python using the .txt type files .. my instructors file open but mine did not when I saved in .txt

```
MF = open("C:/Users/David/Desktop/fruits.txt")
print(MF.read())
```

Expected this file to open in PYTHON IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) however was unable to open the expected file.  I was however able to open the file downloaded from my tutors site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as I don't have enough reputation to add an answer to this question already asked.  So, the reason my files weren't opening is because my original absolute file path was incorrect:

MF = open("C:/Users/David/Desktop/PINS.txt")
print(MF.read())

The problem is I'm running different profiles on my Windows PC, so the current profile in the file path is incorrect.  What needs to change is the following:

MF = open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PINS.txt")
print(MF.read())

Now, the reason I was able to open a file in the first place using the first profile was this file had already been downloaded with that profile!  How confusing!  Of course it will open in that profile .. everytime I saved a file in the current session \Administrator\Desktop\PINS.txt - it could not be found as I was running a new profile.  So, make sure you are indeed in the correct file path directory and profile!  Hope this helps.

Thanks